# How to convert a ".mat" file to opencv's "cv::Mat" using API in "opencvmex.hpp" provided by MATLAB

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv

I tried to read data from ".mat" file created by MATLABand convert a matrix saved in ".mat" to opencv's "cv::Mat" format. That is, firstly open the ".mat" file and get the `mxArrar` type data using `mat.h` and then convert with the API provided by MATLAB, which is defined in `opencvmex.h` file.

I've made the process above clearly, and now I've obtained the `mxArray` successfully. However, when I tried to convert the `mxArray` to `cv::Mat`, the problem occurred and it stated that the function is unparsable. The code is as below:

```cpp
//#include <torch/script.h> // One-stop header.
//
//#include <iostream>
//#include <memory>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define MATLAB_MEX_FILE
#include <mat.h>
#include <opencvmex.hpp>
//#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>



int main(int argc, const char* argv[]){
    // Load mat file as model's input

    MATFile* pmatFile = NULL;
    mxArray* pMxArray = NULL;

    // Open mat file with given API
    pmatFile = matOpen("image.mat", "r");
    // Read mat from .mat file with Name(Here "I" in mat file)
    pMxArray = matGetVariable(pmatFile, "I");
    // Varible to save mat read from mat file
    cv::Mat image_from_mat;
    // Convert from mxArray to cv::Mat
    ocvMxArrayToMat_double(pMxArray, &image_from_mat);

    // Varible to save mat read from mat file
    //cv::Ptr<cv::Mat> image_from_mat = ocvMxArrayToMat_double(pMxArray);
    // Convert from mxArray to cv::Mat
    

    //auto img_tensor = torch::CPU(torch::kFloat32).tensorFromBlob(pMxArray, { 1, 224, 224, 3 });
    return 0;
}
```

This error is thrown

```
LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "struct cv::Ptr<class cv::Mat> __cdecl ocvMxArrayToMat_double(struct mxArray_tag const *,bool)" (?ocvMxArrayToMat_double@@YA?AU?$Ptr@VMat@cv@@@cv@@PEBUmxArray_tag@@_N@Z)，The symbol is referenced in the function `main`    Load_Mat_Cpp    C:\Users\Dalek\Documents\Private\UCAS_SIA\CPP_Reconstruction\Load_Mat_Cpp\main.obj
```

The project is configured in VS2019 and the prop file has content below:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets" />
  <PropertyGroup Label="UserMacros" />
  <PropertyGroup />
  <ItemDefinitionGroup>
    <ClCompile>
      <AdditionalIncludeDirectories>C:\tools\opencv\build\include\opencv2;C:\tools\opencv\build\include;C:\Program Files\Polyspace\R2021a\extern\include;C:\tools\libtorch\include;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)</AdditionalIncludeDirectories>
    </ClCompile>
    <Link>
      <AdditionalLibraryDirectories>C:\tools\opencv\build\x64\vc15\lib;C:\Program Files\Polyspace\R2021a\extern\lib\win64\microsoft;C:\tools\libtorch\lib;%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories)</AdditionalLibraryDirectories>
      <AdditionalDependencies>asmjit.lib;c10.lib;caffe2_module_test_dynamic.lib;clog.lib;cpuinfo.lib;fbgemm.lib;libprotobufd.lib;libprotobuf-lited.lib;libprotocd.lib;mkldnn.lib;torch_cpu.lib;torch.lib;libmat.lib;libmx.lib;libmex.lib;libeng.lib;opencv_world3413.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)</AdditionalDependencies>
    </Link>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <ItemGroup />
</Project>
```

All the path and dependencies has been checked carefully and should be alright, also the environment variable in `Path` has been well added.

Why does this error occur and how can I convert a .mat file to cv::Mat format?

Comment: that is a **linker** error. you failed to link your program against opencv libs. please check, if opencv_world3413.lib exists, and is accessible

Comment: The function signature in the error message doesn’t match how you use the function. It’s second input argument is a `bool`, and it returns a pointer to the `cv::Mat`.